# How does std::distance() work?

Tags: c++11, vector, stl

I am very much new to C++11 and learning about the STL Libraries. I have written a code which is like this,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void Print( const vector<int> &arrays )
{
   for ( int x : arrays ) cout << x << ' ';
}

int main() {
    int citys, cityPairs, fv, lv, w;
    vector <int> fvarr;
    vector <int> lvarr;
    vector <int> warr;
  vector <int> warr_temp;
  vector <int> disjoint_pairs;

    scanf("%d%d", &citys, &cityPairs);

    for(int nr = 0; nr < cityPairs; nr++){
        scanf("%d%d%d", &fv, &lv, &w);
        fvarr.push_back(fv);
        lvarr.push_back(lv);
        warr.push_back(w);
      warr_temp = warr;
    }

  for (int j = 0; j < citys; j++){
    auto result = min_element(begin(warr_temp), end(warr_temp));
    auto pos_temp = distance(begin(warr_temp), result);
    cout << pos_temp;
    auto pos = distance(begin(warr), result);
    cout << pos;
    disjoint_pairs.push_back(fvarr[pos]);
    disjoint_pairs.push_back(lvarr[pos]);
    warr_temp.erase(warr_temp.begin() + pos_temp);
  }
  // Print(disjoint_pairs);
}
```

What i am doing in this code is i am taking 3 vectors and 1 vector to copy the last one `warr_temp = warr;`. Then i am checking the minimum value in vector`warr_temp` and storing it's index in `pos_temp`, next i am storing that min value's index from vector `warr` into `pos`.

Now the problem is the first `cout` which is `pos_temp` giving me correct values but the second one which is `pos` giving me the output something like this,

```
-61-62-63-64
```

why is this happening? what are these numbers? are they pointers? I know that distance is a template so what is the right way to implement this?

If anyone can clear my doubts that would be very helpfull.
Sorry if stupid question!!!

Comment: off-topic: fv, lv & w should be limited to the scope of the for loop itself & not declared outside. Also, consider `std::cin >> fv >> lv >> w;`  while writing in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is `auto pos = distance(begin(warr), result);` line. It gives unpredictable results because `result` and `begin(warr)` belong to different vectors.

`result` is iterator pointing to `warr_temp` element, it cannot be mixed with iterators pointing to `warr` elements like `begin(warr)`.

To get element position in `warr` vector use `std::find(begin(warr), end(warr), *result)` instead:

```
auto warr_res = std::find(begin(warr), end(warr), *result);
auto pos = distance(begin(warr), warr_res);
```

Comment: Hi Rost, I have used your way it is giving me an error like this ''no match for ‘operator<<’" " on this line "cout << pos;" . however if i print it like this "cout << *pos"  then it is giving me the numbers which are in those indexes but not the indexes.

Comment: @Proloy see updated answer. `std::find` gives you iterator as well, you shall apply `std::distance` to it to obtain index.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing this!!